# "update --memory" can not work

Tags: docker

> Docker Version :17.04.0-ce
>
> os :windows 7
>
> I start container using the command :`docker run -it -memory 4096MB <container-id>`
>
> check the memory using the command :`docker stats --no-stream | grep <container-id>`
>   the result is :

```
5fbc6df8f90f        0.23%               86.52 MB / 995.8 Mib   2.59%               648B / 0B   17.2G / 608 MB   31
```

when update the memory,the result is also the same:

```
$ docker update -m 4500MB --memory-swap 4500MB --memory-reservation 4500MB 5fbc6df8f90f               
5fbc6df8f90f
$ docker stats --no-stream | grep 5fbc6df8f90f                                                        
5fbc6df8f90f         0.23%               86.52 MB / 995.8 Mib   2.59%               648B / 0B   17.2G / 608 MB   31
```

why "--memory" can not work ,the memory is always the same 995.8Mib?

Answer (score 0):

The `docker stats` command is showing you how much memory the entire docker host has, or with D4W, how much memory you have in the Linux VM. To increase this threshold, go into the settings of Docker to change the memory allocated to the VM. See [this documentation](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/#advanced) for more details.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is indeed the problem that  entire docker host do not have enough memory. Fist, "docker-machine stop" is used to stop the virtual machine. Then, "VirtualBox" is used to modify the memory.